# How to include a XML Tag with in the SOAP Request

Tags: xml, soapui

I have a simple SOAP request , as shown below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.bayer.com/" xmlns:chim="http://scivantage.com/tata">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:strategy>
         <request>
            <xmlMessage>?</xmlMessage>
          </request>
      </ser:strategy>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In the Simple SOAP Request above 
within the  xmlMessage Tag , i need to include the following XML data

```
<accountid>384</accountid>
<userid>testuser</userid>
```

Please tell me how can i include these two tags with in the question mark here ??

Answer (score 2):

You can use CDATA (where the text is not parsed) and re-parse the xmlMessage on client. See:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.bayer.com/" xmlns:chim="http://scivantage.com/tata">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:strategy>
         <request>
            <xmlMessage><![CDATA[<accountid>384</accountid><userid>testuser</userid>]]>/xmlMessage>
          </request>
      </ser:strategy>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Within CData its accepting only one xml element , for instance <soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
          <soap11env:Header></soap11env:Header>
          <soap11env:Body>
<strategy>
            <request>
 <fixmlMessage>
<![CDATA[<accountid>38400016</accountid>]]>
</fixmlMessage>
</request>
</strategy>
          </soap11env:Body>
        </soap11env:Envelope>      , when i tried to include both the tags it is not working

Comment: _Try this:_ <xmlMessage><![CDATA[<accountid>384</accountid>]]><![CDATA[<userid>testuser</userid>]]></xmlMessage>